# Ruby on Rails - Accessing Parent Attribute Though One to Many Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, one-to-many

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails and am having issues using a one to many association I set up between two models.  Here is the code for the two models that define the one to many association:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews, -> { order 'created_at DESC' }, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :share_locations, dependent: :destroy
end

class ShareLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end
```

In a view controller I find a `ShareLocation` instance and attempt to change an attribute of the `Location` it belongs to.

```
@share_location = ShareLocation.find_by(share_code: share_code)

if @share_location
  @share_location.is_valid = false
  @share_location.location.owner_id = new_owner_id
  @share_location.save
end
```

When I change the `is_valid` attribute of the `ShareLocation` instance it properly updates upon save.  However when I attempt to update the `owner_id` of the `Location` that the `ShareLocation` belongs to nothing seems to happen.  I am pretty new at this and hope this question hasn't already been asked/answered.  I did some research and found many questions that mentioned `nested attributes` and `:foreign_key`.  I can't seem to grasp these concepts and am having trouble seeing how they could help or be applied to my situation.  Could someone please explain to me how to solve this issue and what exactly I am doing wrong.  If this question is a repeat please point me in the right direction and I will remove it.

Comment: With this, do you get location object `@share_location.location`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you're updating 2 objects: `share_location` AND `location`, but saving only `share_location`. To save both objects, you can:

```
if @share_location
  @share_location.is_valid = false
  @share_location.save

  @share_location.location.owner_id = new_owner_id
  @share_location.location.save
end
```

OR if you want to save associated models automatically, you could use [`:autosave`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html) option on your association:

> AutosaveAssociation is a module that takes care of automatically saving associated records when their parent is saved.

I didn't try, but it should work with `belongs_to`:

```
class ShareLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location, autosave: true
end
```

Having this, you should be able to save parent(`share_location`) and Rails will take care of saving associated `location` automatically.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much that did the trick! @Rustam A. Gasanov

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `autosave`, I thought it should be working but I just looked this up

> When the :autosave option is not present then new association records are saved but the updated association records are not saved

So this is why your update isn't saved, to fix this you need to force autosave

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :share_locations, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
end
```